# Changing the font of the title and abstract of my article

Tags: fonts, sectsty, typefaces

I am trying to use two different fonts in my article. I used the 'sectsty' package to change the font of all the section titles. I now want to change the font of the title of my article to the font that I have used for the section headings.

I also want to change the font used for the title and text of the abstract.

How do I go about doing this?

I want to use the ULG Letter Gothic font. I have installed the font and include it in my article by using

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{ulgothic}
```

Edit: I have a sample document attached

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[linesnumbered,lined,boxed,commentsnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 left=25mm,
 right=25mm,
 top=30mm,
 bottom=40mm,
 }

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{ulgothic}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\ttfamily}


\usepackage[sfdefault,light,condensed]{roboto}  


\usepackage{flushend}
\usepackage{abstract}


\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\title{Letter Gothic and Roboto}
\author{Julius\\ Department of Physics\\ BITS-Pilani Hyderabad}
\date{}

\twocolumn[
\maketitle              
\begin{onecolabstract}
\blindtext
\end{onecolabstract}
]

\section{Introduction}
\Blindtext
\section{Discussion}
\Blindtext
\Blindtext
\section{Conclusion}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: How do you create your titles and abstract? These things are very specific to the `\documentclass` you might be using. In fact, why not create a small document that showcases just the important parts that you are addressing in your question, and allows us to copy-and-paste-and-compile it to replicate your current results. That would be awesome!

Comment: Please see the edit to the question. I have attached a sample document.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Here is how I did for the title:

```
\let\oldabstractname\abstractname
\renewcommand*\abstractname{{\emph{\oldabstractname}}}
```

In this case I am simply using `\emph` but you can replace it with your own style.

Note that this solution does not remove previous style. If you need it consider using `\normalfont` or replacing `\oldabstractname` with the actual abstract title.

For the abstract body style, I have changed it inside the abstract environment.

Comment: This at the very least is not good style: the abstractname is meant to be pure text that may be used other places in the document.  The environment should be doing the formatting.

Comment: I agree! My solution is actually an hack! Can you please provide your solution?

Comment: You want to change `\abstractnamefont` instead.